# how to detect which cell is clicked then generate next view according to it in iphone uitableview?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, sqlite

hello all i am new to iphone development i am working on a application called flash cards...

my problem is i want to generate flash cards from database...

here is some code to explain

home screen----
   index View
   categoryView
   TileView
   bookmarks
   search 
   download

indexView is a uitableView

category1(section header title)
 flashCard1
 flashcard2
 flashcard3
category2(section header title)
 flashcard4
 flashcard5
 flashcard6

now i want to pass the flashcard's from categoryid so in different category flashcards related to the category should be shown. and when click on first flash card the flashcardid should be passed to the query from which i can generate the questions.and also the flashCradsmust be distinct by category type..for example..if categorytype=1 the the flash cards should be of type multiple choice if categorytype=2 the flashcards should be of type vocabulary if type=3 flashcards= graphics observation

here is some database info----
cardCategoryInfo(table)
categoryId
categoryName
CategoryType

flashCardInfo(table)
 flashCardId
 categoryId
 flashCardName

flashCardQuestionInfo(table)
questionId
flashCardId
questionText
questionTotalOption
isAudioAvailable
questionAnswer

flashCardMultipleAnswer(table)
questionId
optionId
optionText

someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in your `UITableViewDelegate`. The second argument is the index path, which will give enough information to identify the specific flashcard you want to show.

You will find further information in the [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Introduction/Introduction.html) and the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you get the information from indexPath parameter of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` in your implementation of `UITableViewDelegate`.

Furthermore, you can tag your elements and then pass that tag to your query method. Set tag on element when it is created and then in the handler get the tag first and do work accordingly.